# A question about wlan0 / eth0 and wireshark

Tags: linux, debian, networking, networkmanager

I'm using wireshark to listen to packets on my own personal home network.
I have my Desktop with Debian and Windows 7 running and my laptop is running the same setup; Debian and Windows 7.

I installed wireshark on both.

When on my laptop, I can listen to packets on wlan0. When I browse the web, the packets are captured and all is good.

When on my desktop, I can listen to packets on eth0. When I browse the web and etc, the packets are captured and all is good.

However, when on my laptop (wlan0) and want to listen to packets coming in/out on eth0 - which my desktop computer is on, I obviously get no results.

#### To the Question:

If I want to use my laptop and monitor the packets coming in and out from my desktop  or just simply on both wlan0 and eth0, how could I do this?

This is what it all looks like.
As you can see, there is no IP address at eth0. (This is from my laptop, where wlan0 has an IP address).

[image]

and here is another perspective

[image]

I know it's a small image but if you look closely, under eth0  there is no ip address.. but just below that, wlan0, has a bunch of information there and an ip address.

Comment: Use SSH to log in to the desktop and run a second wireshark instance there?

Comment: Can you show us what you're getting? It's not really clear how you're running wireshark. Ae you using `tshark` and telling it to listen on these interfaces (eth0, wlan0)?

Comment: How are the machines connected ? "eth0 - which my desktop computer is on" Sorry if I misunderstood, but on your laptop, eth0 is *your laptop's* ethernet card. Is your desktop really connected to your laptop's ethernet card ? It looks disconnected.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm explaining it terribly.

My Desktop is connected via an ethernet cable.
So when I `ifconfig` it shows that I am using eth0.

For my laptop, it's connected wireless and when I `ifconfig` it shows that my packets are received/sent on wlan0.

Comment: And both are connected to a home router ? Not to each other ? So it's perfectly normal that you don't see any packet (or ip address) on the laptop's eth0, it is disconnected. To see the traffic for both machines you'd have to be on the router. (eth0 on the desktop is the desktop's network card, but on the laptop it is the laptop's (wired) network card, there are no packets to capture) (also use @name to notify the user of your answer in comments)

Comment: @Leiaz 
You said I'd have to be on the router...

How would I do that via wireshark since all I see are wlan0, eth0, lo?

Comment: You'd have to run wireshark on the router. Wireshark captures packets on any interface of the machine it runs on, but it can't magically get packets that never arrive to that machine.

Comment: [Or you can do it if you connect to your router through ssh apparently](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapInterfaceRemoteSection.html)

Comment: But the GUI doesn't do it automagically, [there are more explanations here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes) (and of course you need some utility to capture on the target machine : tshark, tcpdump ..)

Comment: Thank's a lot. Its mostly my incompetence with wireshark that caused me the most trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding what the specific problem is. However if the most important thing is just make it capture (ie work) packets use the `any` interface. Wireshark will then capture traffic on eth0/wlan0/lo.